# is Blazor Component Utilities compatible with Core 2.1 or 2.2?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

is Blazor Component Utilities compatible with Core 2.1 or 2.2 ?

When I try to compile a 2.1 or 2.2 compatible project I'm always seeing

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.802/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(5,5):

Error NETSDK1064: Package BlazorComponentUtilities, version 1.1.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. (NETSDK1064) (ultaLINK)

However with Core 3.0 and preview and above I don't get this error. Anyone know why?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorComponentUtilities/

The website here says dotnet 2.0 is compatible, so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not you need to use dotnet core 3.0
If I remember well 1st preview was built with .Net Core 2.1, but since preview 5 is .Net core 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with blazor you should have .net core 3.0. You can use VS 2019 or download manually from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-windows-x64-installer